# set value with cfif cfelse Coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to set value
If it matched the output should be renamed as "INFORMATION AVAILABLE" if not as "NO MATCH".

Thank you for your help and tricks

```html
<cfquery name="gethi" datasource="testdb">
    select resp from t_tes x where service=upper('B76Z7') and rownum <=1
    and resp Like ('%OK%')
</cfquery>

<cfif gethi.resp is "">
    <cfset gethi.resp="INFORMATION AVAILABLE">
    <cfoutput>#gethi.resp#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>gethi.resp="NO MATCH"</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

What can be done that it works as requested? any tips? thank you

Comment: Why don't you simply output `"INFORMATION AVAILABLE"` and leave the value of `gethi.resp` alone?

Comment: because ` "INFORMATION AVAILABLE"  ` don't exist in the query i just want to set another value if the query exist give a value and if not give another value. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Yes, you want to set the value of `gethi.resp`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that what you are trying to accomplish is to determine whether the query returns a match or not and to display information on whether a match was found or not.

I don't see that you actually need to set a query cell. I don't see that you actually need to set any variable.

```
<cfquery name="MyQuery" datasource="testdb">
    select resp from t_tes x where service=upper('B76Z7') and rownum <=1
    and resp Like ('%OK%')
</cfquery>

<cfif MyQuery.RecordCount eq 0>
    NO MATCH
<cfelse>
    INFORMATION AVAILABLE
</cfif>
```

Comment: Yep. If you don't need the "resp" data for anything, you could also just do a `count(*) AS MatchFound` and then `<cfif MyQuery.MatchFound>`. No point returning a big string if it's never used.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you do not even have to do what you are doing here, but I do not have much information, so based on what you want:

```
<cfif gethi.resp is "">
 <cfset gethi.resp="INFORMATION AVAILABLE">
 <cfoutput>#gethi.resp#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
 <cfset gethi.resp="NO MATCH">
 <cfoutput>#gethi.resp#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

I reckon that you may want to check if there is some value in gethi.resp, rather than comparing it with blank string. So maybe:

```
<cfif Len(gethi.resp)>
 <cfset gethi.resp="INFORMATION AVAILABLE">
 <cfoutput>#gethi.resp#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
 <cfset gethi.resp="NO MATCH">
 <cfoutput>#gethi.resp#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You cannot set query fields like that, that's exactly the issue the OP has. But I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't need to set a query field. What's the point of setting a query field to "X" and then outputting the query field when you can output "X" directly?

Comment: What stops you from setting query fields like that? OP seems new to CF  so why not help him get a move on.

Comment: I am pretty sure `QuerySetCell()` is needed to set query fields.

Comment: @Tomalak - technically it can be done without QuerySetCell(), but ... agreed it's not necessary. Mixing data and preso logic like this isn't a great practice IMO.